# I don't know why no response with POST request in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please understand this is a website in korea. So there is korean.

What the problem is - I tried to make same as POST request in browser.

But the response is nothing comes like an infinite loop.

This is a test code.

```
var request = require('request');

// Set the headers
var headers = {
    'Host': 'www.onnara.go.kr',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'ko-KR,ko;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Referer': 'http://www.onnara.go.kr/OnnaraServiceMA/onnaraCommon/mainPage.do',
    'Content-Length': '224',
    'Cookie': 'onrMapHelpPopup=onrMapHelpPopup; JSESSIonID=D3Tcd2nTJp3aswF1VGjy2pJJX9bRRXsjfhf41yZgL22FgnqzQ1OXEoeKnxwPhH6H.ONRPGIS1_servlet_OnnaraServiceMA; favoriteList=null%3B2917010100100110000%2F%EA%B4%91%EC%A3%BC%EA%B4%91%EC%97%AD%EC%8B%9C%20%EB%B6%81%EA%B5%AC%20%EC%A4%91%ED%9D%A5%EB%8F%99%2011%2FrBldg',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
}

// Configure the request
var options = {
    url: 'http://www.onnara.go.kr/OnnaraServiceMA/proxy/proxy.jsp?url=',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: headers,
    form: {
            "url": "http://192.168.10.30:9090/OnnaraServiceBE/getTotalSrchData.do",
            "keyWrd": "서울 강남구",
            "authKey": "authNumber1234"
          }
}

// Start the request
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    console.log(body)
})
```

I just leave the image link is you can check the datas and response in browser

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsXaK.jpg

First image is header message.

Second is form data.

Last one is response message.

Please solve why response doesn't come in node.js.

Comment: Should the service do a callback to the url you link in `options.form.url`? If so, `192.168.10.30` isn't reachable by onnara server: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Then isn't there any way I can send request and recieve response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider handling errors better in your `request()` call. Doing so will point you towards the problem your having by letting you know at what point the request fails. Here's an example request template I use direct from [request NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) docs:

```
var request = require('request');
request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage. 
  } else {
    console.warn(response.statusCode)
    console.error(error)     
  }
})
```

Comment: I just ignored the exception handling. But therer is no error and also no response means I don't get any message like infinite loop. no reponse no answer.. nothing~ so I dont' know why but  I will look into rpadovani's answer.